# Sigma algebra question

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $Σ_1$ and $Σ_2$ be two sigma-algebras on the same set $X$, such that their union $Σ_1 ∪Σ_2$ is also a sigma-algebra. Prove that for $A,B ⊆ X$ such that $A ∈ Σ_1 \setminus Σ_2$ and $B ∈ Σ_2 \setminus Σ_1$ it always holds that $A∩B \neq\emptyset$.

---

I cant see how it isn't equal to the empty set. $A$ is in sigma $1$ but not in $2$. And $B$ is in $2$ but not in $1$ so they must be disjoint so their intersection must have nothing in common so it must be the empty set.

EDIT: $A,B \in \Sigma_1 \cup \Sigma_2=\Sigma$ so $(X \setminus A),(X \setminus B) \in \Sigma$ so $(X \setminus A) \cap (X \setminus B)=\emptyset \in \Sigma$ then $(X \setminus A)^c \cap (X \setminus B)^c=A \cap B=\emptyset ^c=X \in \Sigma$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $A,B ⊆ X$ such that $A ∈ Σ_1 \setminus Σ_2$ and 
$B ∈ Σ_2 \setminus Σ_1$.

Since $Σ_1 ∪Σ_2$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $A,B\in Σ_1 ∪Σ_2$, we have $A \cup B\in Σ_1 ∪Σ_2$. So $A \cup B\in Σ_1 $ or $A \cup B\in Σ_2$.

Suppose  $A \cup B\in Σ_1 $. Let us prove $A\cap B \notin Σ_1$.  In fact, if  $A\cap B \in Σ_1$, we would have 
$$B= ((A \cup B)\setminus A)\cup (A\cap B) \in  Σ_1 $$ 
Contradiction, as $B ∈ Σ_2 \setminus Σ_1$. So $A\cap B \notin Σ_1$ and in particular $A\cap B \neq \emptyset$.

Now, Suppose  $A \cup B\in Σ_2 $. Let us prove $A\cap B \notin Σ_2$.  In fact, if  $A\cap B \in Σ_2$, we would have 
$$A= ((A \cup B)\setminus B)\cup (A\cap B) \in  Σ_2 $$ 
Contradiction, as $A ∈ Σ_1 \setminus Σ_2$. So $A\cap B \notin Σ_2$ and in particular $A\cap B \neq \emptyset$.

So, in both cases we have $A\cap B \neq \emptyset$.

**Important Remark:** In fact, the statement "for $A,B ⊆ X$ such that $A ∈ Σ_1 \setminus Σ_2$ and $B ∈ Σ_2 \setminus Σ_1$ it always holds that $A∩B \neq\emptyset$" is vacuously true, because of the following result:

Let $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ be two $\sigma$-algebras 
on the same set $X$, such that their union 
$\Sigma_1 \cup\Sigma_2$ is also a $\sigma$-algebra. Then either $\Sigma_1 \subseteq \Sigma_2$ or $\Sigma_2 \subseteq \Sigma_1$. In other other, **there is no**  $A,B \subseteq X$ such that $A \in \Sigma_1 \setminus \Sigma_2$ and 
$B \in \Sigma_2 \setminus \Sigma_1$.

**Proof:** Suppose there is $A,B \subseteq X$ such that $A \in \Sigma_1 \setminus \Sigma_2$ and $B \in \Sigma_2 \setminus \Sigma_1$.

Since $Σ_1 ∪Σ_2$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $A,B\in Σ_1 ∪Σ_2$, we have $A \setminus B\in Σ_1 ∪Σ_2$. So $A \setminus B\in Σ_1 $ or $A \setminus B\in Σ_2$

If  $A \setminus B\in Σ_1$ then $A\cap B= A\setminus (A\setminus B) \in \Sigma_1$.

If  $A \setminus B\in Σ_2$ then, since $A= (A \setminus B)\cup (A\cap B)$ and $A \notin \Sigma_2$, we must have that $A\cap B \notin \Sigma_2$. Since $A\cap B\in Σ_1 ∪Σ_2$, we have that $A\cap B \in \Sigma_1$.

So we have proved that $A\cap B \in \Sigma_1$.

Now, from $B \setminus A\in Σ_1 ∪Σ_2$, in a similar way we can prove that $A\cap B \in \Sigma_2$.  So we have $A\cap B \in \Sigma_1 \cap \Sigma_2$

Finally, note that $A \cup B\in Σ_1 ∪ Σ_2$.

If $A \cup B\in Σ_1$ then 
$B= ((A \cup B)\setminus A)\cup (A\cap B) \in  Σ_1 $.
Contradiction, as $B ∈ Σ_2 \setminus Σ_1$.

If $A \cup B\in Σ_2$ then 
$A= ((A \cup B)\setminus B)\cup (A\cap B) \in  Σ_2 $. 
Contradiction, as $A ∈ Σ_1 \setminus Σ_2$.

So **there is no**  $A,B \subseteq X$ such that $A \in \Sigma_1 \setminus \Sigma_2$ and $B \in \Sigma_2 \setminus \Sigma_1$. So either $\Sigma_1 \subseteq \Sigma_2$ or $\Sigma_2 \subseteq \Sigma_1$.

Comment: I don't understand how $A \cup B \in \Sigma_1$ because this is saying that A and B are in sigma 1 but we are told that B is not in sigma 1.

Comment: @snowman , Let us go step by step. **1.** $A \in \Sigma_1$ and $B \in \Sigma_2$. **2.** So, $A, B \in   \Sigma_1 \cup \Sigma_2$. **3.** But $\Sigma_1 \cup \Sigma_2$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, so, from 2, we have $A \cup B \in   \Sigma_1 \cup \Sigma_2$. **4.** (now, how an element can be in the union of two classes?) So $A \cup B \in   \Sigma_1$ OR $A \cup B \in   \Sigma_2$. It is why we have two cases: "if  $A \cup B \in   \Sigma_1$ ..."  and "if  $A \cup B \in   \Sigma_2$ ...".

Answer (score 1):

The key issue is that the sigma algebras are required to have a union which is *also* a sigma algebra.   What is required for that to happen?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you prove $(X\setminus A)\cap (X\setminus B)=\emptyset$.

Clearly $A\cup B\in\Sigma_1\cup\Sigma_2$. W.l.o.g. $A\cup B\in \Sigma_1$. Suppose $A\cap B=\emptyset$, then $(A\cup B)\setminus A = B\in\Sigma_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Some people are addressing the question directly; here I will address instead what appears to be a misunderstanding involved.

Suppose $X= \{a,b,c,d\},\quad$ $\Sigma_1 = \Big\{ \{a,b\},\  \{c,d\} \Big\},\quad$ and $\Sigma_1 = \Big\{ \{a,c\},\  \{b,d\} \Big\}$.

Then we have

- $\{a,b\}\in\Sigma_1\setminus\Sigma_2$, and
- $\{a,c\}\in\Sigma_2 \setminus\Sigma_1$, and
- the intersection of those two sets is $\{a\}$, which is not empty.

(In this case the union is not a sigma-algebra, but I think this example may nonetheless show what is wrong in the logic that led to the mistaken conclusion.)